# while True dentro de while True

Tags: while, break

como faço pra finalizar a sessão totalmente no while True dentro de outro? Ex: Eu fiz com break, porém está finalizando somente ele dentro de outro (while True).
olha um exemplo abaixo.

```
while True:
    test = input('Digite pra ir pro proximo while True: ')
    while True:
        test1 = input('Digite (S) pra sair totalmente: ').upper()
        if test1 == 'S':
            break
```

Comment: sim, o break só sai da execução do último while... que tal ao invés de usar um `while true`, colocar uma condição que possa sair por sí própria?, por exemplo algo como `while test1 != "S"`?

Comment: Isso não parece fazer muito sentido, certamente deve escrever esse código de outra forma e aí esse problema não existiria.

Comment: while True:
    test = input('Digite pra ir no proximo while True: ')
    test1 = input('Digite (S) pra sair totalmente: ').upper()
    while test1 != "S":
        test1 = input('Digite (S) pra sair totalmente: ').upper()
    else:
        break

Comment: ficaria desse jeito?

Comment: Maniero, e qual seria outra forma?

Answer (score 0):

Se é uma situação criada como um passa tempo ou quebra cabeças, pode-se levantar uma [exceção](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/errors.html) tratada:

```
while True:
  try:
    test = input('Digite pra ir pro proximo while True: ')
    while True:
        test1 = input('Digite (S) pra sair totalmente: ').upper()
        if test1 == 'S':
            raise RuntimeError()
  except RuntimeError:
    break
```

Mas o ideal é a [refatoração](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refatora%C3%A7%C3%A3o) do código:

```
test = None
while True:
  if test is None:
    test = input('Digite pra ir pro proximo while True: ')
  else:
    test1 = input('Digite (S) pra sair totalmente: ').upper()
    if test1 == 'S':
       break
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma outra maneira de sair seria criar uma variável de apoio, ex:

```
exit = False
while True:
    test = input('Digite pra ir pro proximo while True: ')
    while True:
        test1 = input('Digite (S) pra sair totalmente: ').upper()
        if test1 == 'S':
            exit = True
            break
    if exit:
        break
```

Ou:

```
exit = False
while not exit:
    test = input('Digite pra ir pro proximo while True: ')
    while True:
        test1 = input('Digite (S) pra sair totalmente: ').upper()
        if test1 == 'S':
            exit = True
            break
```

Answer (score -2):

de acordo com esse link https://stackoverflow.com/a/9038199/2258921 o recomendado é usar um `return`, já que em python não é possível usar um `break 2`.

Comment: e se precisar processar algo dentro do primeiro while, ou ainda depois dele? não me parece uma boa solução

Comment: Nesse caso, você não deveria usar while true para o seu segundo while e sim uma condição que você possa controlar, assim como você comentou: while test1 != "S". Mas como a pergunta começa com "como faço pra finalizar a sessão totalmente no while True dentro de outro", creio que o desejo não é executar algo no primeiro while e sim apenas terminar a execução.

Comment: é esse mesmo o ponto, talvez colocar isso na sua resposta fique melhor... é como "olha, o return faria isso, mas não é a melhor solução, bla bla bla", é legal sempre dar uma melhor solução. é como aquela brincadeira "meu código está dando erro! comenta ele que para de dar erro" :)

Comment: Não tem lógica usar dois While True, utilize apenas um e controle o que vc quer com if